# speedbar, defn-, clojure-mode

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm using Emacs 24 on OSX.

I'm using speedbar (from Emacs) + clojure-mode (from list-packages -> install).

Let Foo.clj contain the following content:

```
(defn foo ... )
(defn- bar ...)
```

In clojure land, this means that foo is meant to be a public function and bar is meant to be a private function.

Right now, both "foo" and "bar" show up in the speedbar. I would like "foo" to show up, and "bar" to not show up.

Thus, my question: how is "speedbar" getting a list of tags from clojure-mode ? And how can I edit this list so that "foo" (from defn) shows up while "bar" (from defn-) does not show up?

Thanks!

Comment: My speedbar doesn't show any Clojure vars. Are you using semantic? Most likely the metadata won't be read.

Comment: I'm getting a proper behavior for `ac-nrepl`. You can switch or adapt it to `speedbar`

Comment: Speedbar uses `imenu` based upon the major-mode's method of handling this -- e.g., `imenu-create-index-function` -- Speedbar just adds some stuff like sorting and truncation of the incoming values from `imenu--make-index-alist`